# IBM DW001/E0 introductory course for Bluemix

Tags: ibm-cloud

Need to know whether the links for this course are under maintenance currently. Trying to open the link without much success.

Comment: You mean [these](https://google.com/search?q=ibm%20dw001/e0)? Google cache says they were still up two days ago, so I would suspect its a temporary problem.

Comment: thanks for the information.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about programming

Answer (score 0):

[This link](https://developer.ibm.com/dwcourses/courses/IBM_developerWorks/DW001/2015_summer/about) should take you to the course. It requires its own log-in, separate from your main IBM login ID. Please ask questions about IBM offerings at [IBM developerWorks Answers](https://developer.ibm.com/answers/smart-spaces/12/bluemix.html). Stack Overflow is for technical programming questions.